# Calling a model method at a specific time (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails model that has a column called `expiration_date`. Once the expiration date is reached, I want another column on the model to be modified (e.g. `expired = true`). What are some good ways of doing this?

Ideally I'd like a model function to be called at the exact moment the expiry date is reached.

Comment: is there anything else you want to do except setting `expired = true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the scenario you describe, the best solution is to have an `expired` method instead of a column, that would return true iff the `expiration_date` is greater or equal than the current date.

For other scenarios, I would go with a DB scheduled event triggering a stored procedure. That procedure would check the `expiration_date` column for all the rows in the model table, and update the `expired` (or other(s)) column(s) accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `delayed_job` gem. After installing delayed_job gem do the following:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :set_expiry_timer

  # register the timer
  def set_expiry_timer
    delay(:run_at => expiration_date).expire
  end

  def expire
    update_attribute(:expired, true) unless expired?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a scheduler to automate this? Something like [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Cron](https://github.com/javan/whenever) would work fine.

Then in your scheduled task you could have something like this:

```
if foo.expiration_date < Time.now
  foo.is_expired = true
  foo.save
end
```