# Ruby On Rails delayed_job not calling method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Does anyone know why the following will not work. Is it my code? I'm trying to call the assign_picks at specific times but I could not get it to work. I then tried the below (in 5 minutes time).

I've been following the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934661/calling-a-model-method-at-a-specific-time-ruby-on-rails) stackoverflow post

I rolled back the db and then migrated again but nothing happens after 5 minutes. I've tested the assign_picks method by calling it on a button press and it works fine.

Any ideas? I'v been stuck here for hours.

Thanks for reading.

Edit:

I meant to mention that I'm using a virtual machine on Nitrious.io. Would that have anything to do with it?

> Models/match.rb

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :block, :round, :date, :day, :time, :venue, :team1, :team2, :played, :result, :resultString
  has_many :match_picks
  has_many :current_blocks
  after_create :set_expiry_timer

    # register the timer
  def set_expiry_timer
    delay(:run_at => 5.minutes.from_now).assign_picks
  end  


  def assign_picks
    @current_blocks = CurrentBlock.where(:id => 1)
    @users = User.where(:curr_block != @current_blocks[0].block)
    @matches = Match.where(:block => @current_blocks[0].block)    

    @users.each do |user|
      @matches.each do |match|
    MatchPick.create!(:userID => user.id, :matchID => match.id, :blockID => @current_blocks[0].block, :userPick => (0..2).to_a.sample)
      end
    end
      # Increase the current block for application
       CurrentBlock.where(:id => 1).each do |cb|
    cb.update_attribute(:block, cb.block + 1)
     end      
  end  

end
```